# Count specific duplicates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have problem to count the number of employees (EmpID) with a phone number (PhoneNum) assigned also to some other employee. But only for specific organization (OrgID)

My Oracle tables looks like this:

```
TABLE OrgEmployees (OrgID, EmpID, ...)
TABLE PhoneNums (ID, EmpID, PhoneNum, ...)
```

Sample data for the specific organization:

```
SELECT pn.EmpID, pn.PhoneNum FROM PhoneNums pn
WHERE EmpID IN (SELECT DISTINCT EmpID FROM OrgEmployees oe
                WHERE oe.OrgID = 'XY');

EmpID   PhoneNum
723     963264
731     963264
973     963276
729     963276
103     963450
725     963450
722     963460
731     963460
722     963462
731     963462
427     995487
295     995487
771     123151
503     123151
721     963265
104     963266
```

Correct result on above set of data should be **14**.

My attempts went like this:

```
SELECT pn.PhoneNum, count(pn.EmpID) FROM PhoneNums pn
WHERE pn.EmpID IN (SELECT oe.EmpID FROM OrgEmployees oe
                   WHERE oe.OrgID = 'XY') 
GROUP BY pn.PhoneNum
HAVING count (*) > 1
ORDER BY pn.PhoneNum;
```

But how could I consider if EmpID are the same or not?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT pn.PhoneNum, COUNT(DISTINCT pn.EmpID)
FROM PhoneNums pn
WHERE pn.EmpID IN (SELECT oe.EmpID
                   FROM OrgEmployees oe
                   WHERE oe.OrgID = 'XY'
                  ) 
GROUP BY pn.PhoneNum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pn.EmpID) > 1
ORDER BY pn.PhoneNum;
```

I would be more inclined to write this using `JOIN` rather than `IN`:

```
SELECT pn.PhoneNum, COUNT(DISTINCT pn.EmpID)
FROM PhoneNums pn JOIN
     OrgEmployees oe
     ON oe.OrgID = 'XY' AND pn.EmpID = oe.EmpID
GROUP BY pn.PhoneNum
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pn.EmpID) > 1
ORDER BY pn.PhoneNum;
```